# What is the fastest way to put 8 bit integer in 16 bit integer array

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization

I am working on a program that processes images. If I could store RGBA values in 16bit integers I could increase performance by using SSE (without the risk of overflow). However the conversion from 8 bit integers to 16 bit integers is the bottleneck. What is the fastest way to put signed 8 bit integers into 16 bit integer array, an efficient equivalent of

```
int8_t a[128];
int16_t b[128];

for (int i=0;i<128;i++)
       b[i]=a[i];
```

I am using openmp and pointers.

Comment: Have you looked into loop vectorization at all? This is almost a textbook example of that.

Comment: @MichaelAlbers Not really. Shouldn't compiler vectorize automatically?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. GCC will at -O3, but otherwise you have to tell it to.

Comment: "The conversion from 8 bit integers to 16 bit integers is the bottleneck": Really??? If you're doing any nontrivial processing on the image, it would be very surprising to me that this would be the bottleneck, even if the conversion is quite inefficient.  Do you have profiling data to support that?

Comment: are you sure you want to use int8_t rather than uint8_t?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some measurements, and on my (fairly noisy) desktop, which sports a 3.1Ghz AMD CPU. I'm not too familiar with the AMD's cache policies, but for this it shouldn't matter too much.

Here's the code: [gist of test.cpp](https://gist.github.com/scraimer/0e8965a38cb235e0565a)
I compiled it with -O2 with GCC 4.92

The results:

```
original: 0.0905usec
aligned64: 0.1191usec
unrolled_8s: 0.0625usec
unrolled_64s: 0.0497usec
```

- original - your original code
- aligned64 - I thought perhaps the alignment was an issue, so I forced it into * 64-bit alignment. It was not the issue.
- unrolled_8s - Unrolled the 128-loop into groups of eight.
- unrolled_64s - Unrolled the 128-loop into groups of 64.

My CPU runs at 3.1Ghz CPU, so let's assume it's about 3 billion cycles per seconds, so that's about 3 cycles per nanosecond.

- original: 90 nsec ~ 270 cycles. Thus (270/128) = 2.11 cycles per copy
- aligned64: 119 nsec ~ 357 cycles. Thus (357/128) = 2.79 cycles per copy
- unrolled_8s: 62 nsec ~ 186 cycles. Thus (186/128) = **1.45 cycles per copy**
- unrolled_64s: 50 nsec ~ 150 cycles. Thus (267/128) = **1.17 cycles per copy**

Please don't just blindly assume that unrolling your loops will be better! I cheated heavily here by abusing two things:

- All the data stays in cache
- All the instructions (code) stay in cache

If all your data is getting invalidated out of the CPU's caches, you may be paying a terrible penalty in re-fetching it all the way back from main memory. In the worst case, the thread doing the copying might be getting tossed off the CPU ("context switch") between each copy. On top of that, the data might be getting invalidated out of the cache. That means you'd be paying hundreds of microseconds per context switch, and hundreds of cycles per memory access.

Answer (score 2):

Clang will vectorize this code with -O2

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>

const int size = 128;
uint8_t a[size];
int16_t b[size];


static __inline__ unsigned long long rdtsc(void)
{
    unsigned hi, lo;
    __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=a"(lo), "=d"(hi));
    return ( (unsigned long long)lo)|( ((unsigned long long)hi)<<32 );
}


void convert(uint8_t* src, int16_t* dest)
{
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    dest[i]=src[i];
}

int main()
{
    int sum1 = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        a[i] = rand();
        sum1 += a[i];
    }
    auto t = rdtsc();
    convert(a, b);
    t = rdtsc() - t;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum2 += b[i];
    }

    printf("%d = %d\n", sum1, sum2);
    printf("t=%llu\n", t);
}
```

This is the code generated by clang++.

```
; The loop inlined from `convert` as a single pass. 
    #APP
    rdtsc
    #NO_APP
    movl    %eax, %esi
    movl    %edx, %ecx
    movq    a(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+8(%rip), %xmm2
    pxor    %xmm0, %xmm0
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+16(%rip)
    movq    a+16(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+24(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+32(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+48(%rip)
    movq    a+32(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+40(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+64(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+80(%rip)
    movq    a+48(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+56(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+96(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+112(%rip)
    movq    a+64(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+72(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+128(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+144(%rip)
    movq    a+80(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+88(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+160(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+176(%rip)
    movq    a+96(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+104(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+192(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+208(%rip)
    movq    a+112(%rip), %xmm1
    movq    a+120(%rip), %xmm2
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm1
    punpcklbw   %xmm0, %xmm2
    movdqa  %xmm1, b+224(%rip)
    movdqa  %xmm2, b+240(%rip)
    #APP
    rdtsc
    #NO_APP
```

For larger sizes, it will take a bit more, since the compiler won't inline to infinite size.

gcc only vectorizes without further options for -O3, but then it generates similar code.

But if you use `-ftree-vectorize`, gcc also produces SSE instructions in -O2.